# Couchbase - Unable to store key and value though bucket is connected to successfully

Tags: store, membase, couchbase

I've been trying to set up a Couchbase server. But unable to store any value and value. 
Following Couchbase manual, I simply install Couchbase, refer the Couchbase Client .NET (Enyim.Caching) into project, then re-configure Couchbase section in app setting with my local pool url (http://local:8091/pools).
I can though connect to connect to bucket through set up CouchbaseClient and CouchbaseClientConfiguration, but unable to store any key-value after that (by .Store(StoreMode.Set, key, value) always returns false).
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that your local pool URL is http://localhost:8091/pools/default and not http://local:8091/pools?  Also, what are the versions of the server and client that you're using?

Thanks.